# Get value by date and hour (Index Match) (updated)

Tags: excel, date, indexing, match

**Update:
Current formula: =INDEX(Test!$B$4:$Y$34;MATCH(A5;$A$5:$A$724;0);MATCH(C5;$C$5:$C$724;0)) it find OK for 2019.01.01 but for 2019.01.02 it jumps to 2019.01.25 Test sheet and take values from that row... cant find reasons for that. Does anyone had similar problem and solution?**

Trying to write formula to get value by date and month.

From datasheet (Screen2) need to get vales to Screen1 P column by Date (column A) and hour (column C).

Formula which I use in Column P:

{=INDEX(Test!$B$4:$Y$34;MATCH(A5;$A$5:$A$724;0);MATCH(C5;$C$5:$C$724;0))}

But it calculates incorrectly. It does not take columns. Maybe anyone know how to fix it or have another, better solution?

[image: Screen1]

[image: Screen2]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll need array formulas. Try enter the following in cell P5:

```
=INDEX(Test!$B$4:$Y$34,MATCH(A5,Test!$A$4:$A$100,0),MATCH(C5,Test!$C$3:$CV$3,0))
```

Edit:
With semicolons the formula is:

```
=INDEX(Test!$B$4:$Y$34;MATCH(A5;Test!$A$4:$A$100;0);MATCH(C5;Test!$C$3:$CV$3;0))
```

Comment: With some system languages (e.g. German) Excel uses semicolons instead of commas in formulas.

Comment: Thanks. I amended the answer to account for that.

Comment: Now it get values for 2019.01.01, but still dont get values for 2019.01.02 etc. Maybe it something wrong with formats or formula...

Comment: The formula I posted uses the values in cells A5 and C5 as lookup values, and it searches for these in the table in the Test sheet. The formula in cell P6 should show a value of 2. Does it? If not, can you reply with the formula that is used in cell P6, and what value it displays?

Comment: F.C Current formula: =INDEX(Test!$B$4:$Y$34;MATCH(A5;$A$5:$A$724;0);MATCH(C5;$C$5:$C$724;0)) ir find OK for 2019.01.01 but for 2019.01.02 ir jumps to 2019.01.25 Test sheet... cant find reason for that.

Comment: I had an error in the formula I posted. Please try the corrected formula in the answer.